# scaling vectors using a sequency of numbers in Python

Tags: python, vector

I want to scale a vector k=[1, 2, 3] multiple times using a sequence of numbers s = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]. The the expected result is [2, 4, 6], [4, 8, 12], .... How could I do this without using loops in Python? Using a loop is not desired, as in my actual problem the length of s is a million, and the actual calculation involves more operations than just a  scaling.

Comment: This is basically the outer product. You should be looking at numpy for this: `np.multiply.outer(k, s).T`

Answer (score 0):

With numpy library

```
import numpy as np

k =[1,2,3]
s=[2,4,6,8,10]

np.multiply.outer(k, s).T

#your result will be:
array([[ 2,  4,  6],
       [ 4,  8, 12],
       [ 6, 12, 18],
       [ 8, 16, 24],
       [10, 20, 30]])
```